# Disable list of holidays in Jquery date picker

Tags: jquery

How to disable a list of holidays using jquery date picker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Datepicker - Disable specific days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677976/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specific-days)

Comment: I think possible duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695961/jquery-datepicker-disable-federal-holidays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var disabledDates = ['08/30/2010', '05/30/2010', '02/14/2011']; 

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) { 
        var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date); 
        if (noWeekend[0]) { 
            return disableDays(date); 
        } else { 
            return noWeekend; 
        } 
} 

function disableDays(date) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < disabledDates.length; i++) { 
        if (new Date(disabledDates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {              
            return [false]; 
        } 
    } 
    return [true]; 
}  

$(.selector).datepicker({minDate: new Date(),beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays, changeYear: true ,changeMonth: true});
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you. Would you know how to disable the next day after the bank holiday also?